# Fetching an image from url takes a lot of time thogh it loads quicky inside a webView

Tags: android

I have an image located at an HTTP url , when i try to load this in a webview inside an activity it doesn't take much time to load , but when i am trying to set it to an ImageView by creating a bitmap as below

```
fis = new FileInputStream(f);
fis = new java.net.URL(filePath).openStream();
bfis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fetch(filePath), null, o2);
fis.close();
```

It takes a lot of time , How can I efficiently set the image to ImageView ?

Also can u explain why it loads quickly in webView while it takes a lot of time in while fetching it from inputstream

Comment: Try to use this library project, its really faster and easy to use.
http://code.google.com/p/android-query/
Down sampling must be applied if you have a big image.

Answer (score 0):

> UrlImageViewHelper will automatically download, save, and cache all
>   the image urls the BitmapDrawables. Duplicate urls will not be loaded
>   into memory twice. Bitmap memory is managed by using a weak reference hash table, so as soon as the image is no longer used by you, it will be garbage collected automatically.

https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper